# PowerApp instead of SharePoint form, but Edit, New and view not working

Tags: powerapp

I want to customize the New, Edit and View forms for a list. To do this, I clicked on "Customize Forms" in SharePoint and then tried to design a separate screen/form in Power App for each of New, Edit and View. I need individual customizations for the three forms.

Unfortunately it doesn't work and following Microsoft's instructions doesn't work either. Are there any known issues for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you've created separate screens and forms, I suspect you probably just need to update your SharePointIntegration control.

1. For initial setup, I would hit "Customize Forms" and then duplicate the screen a couple of times.
2. I'd rename my screens to something like screenNewForm, screenEditForm and screenViewForm
3. I'd then rename the form on each of those screens to newForm, editForm and viewForm.
4. Select the `SharePointIntegration` control and select `OnEdit` from the dropdown.
5. Update the formula to `EditForm(editForm);Navigate(screenEditForm)`
6. Do the same for `OnView` & `OnNew` (obviously replacing editForm & screenEditForm with the appropriate ones.

[image]